# Different html canvas coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

i made 2 deference size html canvas to drawing

1. First canvas = width : 400px,height:200px
2. Second canvas = width : 200px,height :100px

Now when i drawing in first html canvas i send that coordinates(x1,y1,x2,y2) to second canvas.

When first canvas coordinates send in second canvas it's not drawing in same place as first canvas.

is there way to equal first canvas coordinates to second one without changing canvas width and height .

```
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.lineWidth = 5; 
ctx.lineCap = 'round'; 
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"; 
ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y); 
ctx.lineTo(ncoord.x , ncoord.y); 
ctx.stroke(); 


//SECOUND CANVAS
ctx2.beginPath(); 
ctx2.lineWidth = 5; 
ctx2.lineCap = 'round'; 
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red"; 
ctx2.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y); 
ctx2.lineTo(ncoord.x , ncoord.y); 
ctx2.stroke();
```

when user drwaing in canvas 1 i send that coordinates to both canvas. but in second canvas not drawing in same place as canvas 1.
Note : canvas 1 and 2 have deferent width and height.

I need to slove this without changing width height of the both canvas.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you maybe provide some of your code that draws the content on the first and second canvas?

Comment: I added check it please

Comment: Great! What exactly do you mean with “not the same place as the first”? Do you mean that the canvasses are not aligned? Or can it be that you draw with coordinates that exist in canvas1 bot not in canvas2 eg: (300;200)?

Comment: Yeah when i placed a dot in corner of the first canvas  that dot is not placing in same place in second canvas.               Shortly i need to know when i got a canvas coordinates from pc can i equal that coordinates to mobile phone.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to convert the coordinates of canvas1 to the relative coordinates in canvas2? So that (100;100) in canvas1 becomes (50;50)?

Comment: Yeah that's what i need.is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have made the right assumptions to answer your question. I created two different canvases of two different sizes. The coordinates only fit on the first, bigger, canvas.

You can transform the 'big' coordinates to 'small' coordinates by dividing the width or height of the bigger smaller canvases by the bigger canvases.
For example, the height of the big canvas is 200 but the height of the smaller one is 100. If you divide `100 / 200` you get `0.5`. The 'small' coordinates should be half as high as the original ones. See for yourself below:

```js
//just for testing purposes
var coord = {
  x: 320,
  y: 125
};
var ncoord = {
  x: 220,
  y: 90
};

function drawBig() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
  ctx.lineTo(ncoord.x, ncoord.y);
  ctx.stroke();

}

function drawSmall() {
  let bigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  let smallCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");

  //Devide the dimensions of the big and small canvas in order to get the magnification factor:
  let widthDimension = smallCanvas.width / bigCanvas.width;
  let heightDimension = smallCanvas.height / bigCanvas.height

  var ctx2 = smallCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx2.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";

  //Transform the original coordinates to the right dimensions:
  ctx2.moveTo(coord.x * widthDimension, coord.y * heightDimension);
  ctx2.lineTo(ncoord.x * widthDimension, ncoord.y * heightDimension);
  ctx2.stroke();

}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<hr>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="100"></canvas>


<button onclick="drawBig()">draw big canvas</button>
<button onclick="drawSmall()">draw small canvas</button>
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

Comment: @AvishkaHiran well you could do the reverse by devividing the bigCanvas with the smallCanvas.