# Html5 canvas drawing is misplaced after resizing canvas dynamically

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I am placing a circle in a canvas and resizing the canvas dynamically but when doing so my circle is misplaced. I was wondering if anyone could help me out to figure this out. Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bStAq.png) displays a red circle in the middle of the letter 'O' and Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzVTM.png) displays the red circle NOT in its intended position after canvas is resized (it should still continue in the middle the the letter 'O').

Here is my html and javascript:

```js
        var points_x = new Array();
        var points_y = new Array();

        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        var original_width = img.naturalWidth;
        var original_height = img.naturalHeight;
        var current_width = original_width; 

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.width = original_width;
        canvas.height = original_height;

        function saveResizeAndRedisplay(scaleFactor) {
                    
            current_width += scaleFactor;
            img.width = current_width;
            
            // resize the canvas
            canvas.width += scaleFactor;
            canvas.height += scaleFactor;

            for (var i = 0; i < points_x.length; i++) {
                
                //this is where things are going wrong !!!
                points_x[i] += scaleFactor;
                    points_y[i] += scaleFactor;
            }

            redraw_points_after_zoom();
        }

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
            getMousePosition(canvas, e);
        });

        function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {

            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

            points_x.push(x);
            points_y.push(y);

            var radius = 3;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fill();
        }

        function redraw_points_after_zoom() {

            var radius = 3;

            for (var i = 0; i < points_x.length; i++) {

                ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(points_x[i], points_y[i], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                    ctx.fill();
            }
        }

        $("#resizer").click(function() {
          saveResizeAndRedisplay(50);
        });
```

```css
        body {
            background-color: ivory;
            padding:10px;
        }
        canvas {
            border:1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  
  <button id="resizer">Click to resize the canvas</button>

  <br/>
  <img id="img" src="https://www.miamidade.gov/resources/images/services/adopt-a-tree-logo-01-08-2019.png" alt="" style="z-index: 1;position: absolute;">
  
  <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index: 20;position: relative;"></canvas>

</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

P.S.: I don't want to save want to save the contents of the canvas as img and reloading it.

Comment: Maybe [this post on relative canvas coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339928/different-html-canvas-coordinates/) can be of help

Comment: tks ... i will have a look :)

Comment: hey it worked ... had to change a couple of things but the main idea worked ! tks a bunch :D

Comment: Great to hear! Don't forget to upvote if it was a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the canvas is resized, you need to redraw the layout. So you may need to attach the draw function inside resize event. If you are concerned about performance (due to unwanted render for every resize), kindly look into debounce api.

[debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179274/html-canvas-drawing-disappear-on-resizing/63750728#63750728)